# Starting a screen flow inside an overlay modal that I am calling from utility bar using Aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have tried going on the LWC route but there is no functionality like overlay library.
I have solved this issue using $A.createcomponent. But I am facing a bug **while clicking the button for the second time**.

I am calling this inside the aura component I have put inside the Utility bar window.

`<lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>`

There is a button inside utility window that triggers this js function:

```
openFlowOverlay: function (component, event, helper) {
        $A.createComponent(
            "lightning:flow",
            {
                "aura:id": "dynamicFlow",
                
            },
            function (newFlow, status, errorMessage) {
                var overlayLib = component.find("overlayLib");
                var flowName = "ABC_FLOW"; //add your flow API name
                var flow = component.find("dynamicFlow");
                
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
    
                    var flowConfig = {
                        header: "ABC FLOW",
                        body: newFlow,
                        showCloseButton: true,
                        cssClass: "slds-modal_large",
                        closeCallback: function () {
                            
                        }
                    };
                    overlayLib.showCustomModal(flowConfig)
                    .then(function(){
                        flow.startFlow(flowName);
                    });
 
                } else {
                    console.error("Error creating Flow component: " + errorMessage);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

When I open the utility bar and open it and click the button it's running fine. But when I close and try to click the button again I get this error.

[image: This is the error, I am getting when I click the button for second time]

Comment: Have you looked at [lightning-modal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-modal/documentation) or the [SLDS modal blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/)? Either would allow you to avoid Aura.

Comment: I know about them, but I want overlay over the entire window, which disables the user from doing anything else but to close the overlay modal, to my knowledge that is possible through "lightning:overlayLibrary". It has been proposed in the idea exchange
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdd1GUAR/lightningoverlaylibrary-for-lightning-web-components

Comment: Just to clarify, a modal does block interaction with anything behind it.

Comment: yes, but a basic modal will run inside the utility window. Tried and tested. Thats why I am using "lightning:overLayLibrary".

Comment: Well, we have flows run and re-run from LWCs in modals without problems. I must say, we don't do this from the utility bar, instead using global and quick actions. I guess the SLDS modal screen area could be restricted because of the way the utility bar is defined, though I'd recommend you raise that as a separate question.

Comment: You can absolutely, recreate this bug by calling it, by adding a button calls my above function in the Utility bar, and using this  <lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/> inside the html. Its just that when I am running it for the second time the flow variable is undefined.
I know it is unconventional but the requirement is like this